# "File Format Is Not Valid" error while trying to export xlsx file from data table

Tags: excel, vb.net

Excel gives me an error: `excel cannot open the file .xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid`.

Here is my code:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Excel.xlsx")
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode
        Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble)
        Response.Write(x.ToString)
        Response.End()
```

Comment: Excel gives me an error:  excel cannot open the file .xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be like this.

```
 Private Sub DatatableToExcel(ByVal dtTemp As DataTable)
        Dim _excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        wBook = _excel.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dtTemp
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            _excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next

        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                _excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
            Next
        Next

        wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        Dim strFileName As String = "C:\datatable.xlsx"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
        End If

        wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
        wBook.Close()
        _excel.Quit()
    End Sub
```

http://www.authorcode.com/export-datatable-to-excel-in-vb-net/